Cannot fix HttpClient Error in Angular Project
I am trying to set up a runtime configuration value for a URL in my angular project how it is outlined in this thread, and I can't seem to figure out why i am getting a NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient! When to me i think i am adding the module correctly.
This is my app-config.service.ts
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConfigService {

  private appConfig: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    console.log("HttpClient is injected:", http);
  }

  loadAppConfig(): Promise<void>{
    return this.http.get('/assets/config.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => {
        this.appConfig = data;
      });
  }

  // This is an example property ... you can make it however you want.
  get apiBaseUrl() {

    if (!this.appConfig) {
      throw Error('Config file not loaded!');
    }

    return this.appConfig.apiBaseUrl;
  }
}

and this is my app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { AppConfigService } from './app-config.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule, 
            MatIconModule, 
            HttpClientModule],
  template: `
  <main>
    <a [routerLink]="['/']">
      <header class="brand-name">
        <!-- <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon" fontIcon="home"></mat-icon> -->
        <button mat-button class="home-button">
          <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon" fontIcon="home"></mat-icon>
          Home
        </button>
      </header>
    </a>
    <section class="content">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </section>
  </main>
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppConfigService],
      useFactory: (appConfigService: AppConfigService) => {
        return () => {
          //Make sure to return a promise!
          return appConfigService.loadAppConfig();
        };
      }
    }
  ],
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'draft-tool';
  textInput: string = '';
}

I dont know if it is my router link taking me to a different component, but i tried adding the client module the same way in that file as i did in my app.component.ts and it didnt seem to help at all.
I think i may just be missing something fundamentally in how this is working in angular, this is just a side project i'm taking on to learn front end as I have only been a backend dev for years.
I am expecting to be able to load a URL in at runtime so i can change the value when I am doing development, and when I am deployed to my AWS env.

See https://this-is-angular.github.io/angular-guides/docs/standalone-apis/using-the-httpclient-in-a-standalone-angular-application

I tried adding both of those implementations to the bottom of both of these files and it didnt change anything
